# How to merge 2 simple RegEx's?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following C# code to replace `.`'s and `+`'s with spaces:

```
string MyString = "this.is.just+an++example--here!are$more characters";
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace(MyString, @"[\.\+]", " "));
```

Sometimes this might result in excess whitespace (as in, between `an` and `example`).

How can I also add the following RegEx to my existing RegEx, so there is only a single RegEx call?

```
Regex.Replace(MyString, @"[ ]{2,}", " ");
```

This will remove excess whitespace. All other characters should remain untouched.

Any alternate solutions are also welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should match multiple characters in the first place. Change the regexp to `"[\.\+]+"`to match one or more `.` or `+` signs. For example, `"a...++b"` would result in `"a b"`

```
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace(MyString, @"[\.\+]+", " "));
```

Comment: Nice!! Just one question: what about where excess spaces already appear in the string? I.e. `string MyString = "some<space><space>test<space><space><space>hi";`

Comment: Adding \s to the expression should cover that. @"[\.\+\s]+"

Comment: Just add the space to the regex: `[\.\+\ ]+`

Comment: @StevePy `\s` will also match tabs and newlines etc though. It should only match spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this. You don't need to escape the `.` if it is inside a character class

```
[.\+]+|[ ]{2,}
```

Comment: It looks like this also works: `Regex.Replace(MyString, "[.+ ]+", " ")` - is there anything wrong with this? Thanks